# How to capture an exception thrown by an invocation using FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, xunit, fluent-assertions

In FluentAssertions, how does one capture an exception thrown by an invocation? [Exceptions](https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/) shows basic code samples, but in my case I have a `CustomException` with a public enum. I'd like to assert that the correct enum value was thrown.

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
   public MyEnum MyEnum { get; private set; }

   public CustomException(MyEnum myEnum)
   {
      MyEnum = myEnum;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use `.Where()` to apply a custom condition to the caught exception:

```
act.Should().Throw<CustomException>().Where(e => e.MyEnum == MyEnum.Cheese);
```